# Output values from session into a form

Tags: php, session

I am having some problem with trying to output 2 session values.
It works fine when i output only the $_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";

But then i try to output two session values, it does not work. Here is an example of what I have done so far.

```
<?php
session_start();


$_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";
$_SESSION['studentid']="studentid";
echo "Logged in as".$_SESSION['studentid'];
echo "<h3 class='velkommen'>Logga inn som:<span class='spanclass'>" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</span></h3>";

?>
```

The studentid output as studentid.
The page before i did this:

```
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$studentid=$_POST['studentid'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$studentid = stripslashes($studentid);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string($studentid);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
header("location:login_success.php" );
```

Any tip why it only the myusername who is correct?
I need the both values to be in a form

```
<?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="myusername" value="'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'">';
?>
```

Any tip?

Comment: ***stripslashes*** o_O, are you using an outdated, misconfigured PHP version? - ***mysql*** o_O your are using a deprecated Mysql database layer? - ***XSS attacks*** o_O your script is prone to it. If you output HTML ensure you do so, you need to take more care here. --- with so many errors already in there, it's most likely not of interest to the general visitors of this website to see such a question answered. Instead try to figure out what your *concrete* question is and create a reduced but self-containing example *from scratch* that shows your issue.

Comment: lot of work to convert it to mysqli?

Comment: Normally not, but the problem is more the way you ask that quesiton. Isolate the problem first, re-write a new example from scratch that is self-containing and shows the concrete problem. Then ask about it. You should not rewrite your code only you need to ask a question on SO - except for the code you give in the question (no live code is a good rule of thumb).

Comment: thanks for feedback. I think mabye i should try to make the loginpage with mysqli. Im not sure how to explain the problem i have with the session values better. I try look for a good tutorial for mysqli.

Comment: Your problem: because you output it as such: `echo "Logged in as".$_SESSION['studentid'];` - PHP only does what you have coded into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";
        $_SESSION['studentid']="studentid";
        echo "Logged in as".$_SESSION['studentid'];
        echo "<h3 class='velkommen'>Logga inn som:<span class='spanclass'>". $_SESSION['mypassword'] . "</span></h3>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a session for `mypassword`

```
$_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";
$_SESSION['studentid']="studentid";
```

whereas you are doing an `echo` for `$_SESSION['myusername']`

```
echo "<h3 class='velkommen'>Logga inn som:<span class='spanclass'>" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</span></h3>";
```

I dont see any `$_SESSION['myusername']`

What you need to do is, this

```
$_SESSION['myusername']="myusername";
$_SESSION['studentid']="studentid";

echo "Logged in as: ".$_SESSION['studentid'];

    echo "<h3 class='velkommen'>Logga inn som:<span class='spanclass'>" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</span></h3>";
```

Comment: XSS also. If you output HTML, ensure you're doing so. The data inside `$_SESSION` is not HTML encoded, so you need to encode it when you output it.

Comment: thanks for the tip, buts not working, Then i follow Baigs tip it output: Logged in as studentid an Velkommen logga inn som Myusername

Comment: so are you saying it worked? or still having a problem?

Comment: if someone have time to look av the files i can easy send them, but i understrand that that is to much to ask for.

Comment: still problem baig ;(

Comment: you might want to put all/more details in your question then

Comment: here are 3 files.  first, main_login.php

Comment: wich it a table form who leads checklogin.php

Comment: this is checklogin.php. have * out the sensitive info

Comment: <?php
session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="*"; // Mysql username 
$password="*"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="*"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="*"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$studentid=$_POST['$studentid'];

Comment: // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$studentid = stripslashes($studentid);
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string($studentid);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['studentid'] = $studentid;
header("location:login_success.php" );

}
else {
echo "Feil brukernavn eller passord";
echo "<br>";

echo "<a href=main_login.php>Gå tilbake til innlogging</a>";

}
include "header.inc.php";
include "funksjoner.inc.php";
?>

Comment: and this is the last login_success.php:                          <?php session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername']="myusername";
$_SESSION['studentid']="studentid";

echo "Logged in as: ".$_SESSION['studentid'];

    echo "<h3 class='velkommen'>Logga inn som:<span class='spanclass'>" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</span></h3>";
include "header.inc.php";
include "funksjoner.inc.php";
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Innlogget</title>  
    </head><body>
    <!--Knapp til å gå til modulane-->
    <!--Knapp til å logge av-->
    <div class="content">

Comment: <button class="loggavknapp"onClick="location.href='/database/logout.php'">Logg av bruker</button>

<button class="modulknapp" onClick="location.href='/main/main.php'">Til Modulane</button>
    
<h1>Velkommen til MOOC for PHP</h1>
<?php
$tilkobling = kobleTil(); //trenger ikke oppgi databasenavn

//Steg 2: Kjør en SQL-spørring mot databasen 
$sql=('SELECT * FROM epostliste WHERE myusername = "'
  . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername']) . '"')
  or trigger_error(mysql_error());

$resultat = mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);

Comment: while ($nesteRad = mysql_fetch_array($resultat)){
 echo "<h1>Dittbrukernavn er:</h1> " . $nesteRad['myusername'];
 //echo "<br>Din studentid er: " . $nesteRad['studentid'];
}

?>

</div>
</body>
<?php
include "footer.inc.php";
?>
</html>

Comment: Im so sorry, this was looking terrible here

Comment: go to your question and EDIT it